# unable to show multiple graph while using semilogy in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot 3 graph within a single graph with x=1 to 10 and Y as power of 10 using semilogy but only one(the last one) graph is plotted and the remaining remains unploted.

```
semilogy(x,getval4(x,5),'-og');
semilogy(x,getval4(x,10),'--Xb');
semilogy(x,getval4(x,20),'--r');
```

Only `semilogy(x,getval4(x,20),'--r');`is plotted .I am new to mat lab so please sujjest me a way to plot all the three graphs.Also,I would like to have a grid too

Comment: [`hold`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do

```
semilogy(x,getval4(x,5),'-og');
hold on ;
semilogy(x,getval4(x,10),'--Xb');
semilogy(x,getval4(x,20),'--r');
```

(note the hold on *after* the first semilogy, not before)

Comment: Awesome!..That worked..Cheers!

Comment: @Abx please mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
plot(x,getval4(x,5),'-og');
hold on ;
plot(x,getval4(x,10),'--Xb');
plot(x,getval4(x,20),'--r');
set(gca,'yscale','log')
```